# Как проверить json ответ на пустое значение в jmeter тест?

Tags: юнит-тесты, jmeter

Например как проверить, что `title` пусто

```
{
"title":""
}
```

Answer (score 1):

С помощью регулярных выражений (см. Post Processors - Regular Expression Extractor или [плагина](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/JSONPathExtractor/).

Answer (score 0):

Использовать JSON Path PostProcessor (появился в версии 3.0)

Answer (score 0):

Для проверки ответа используйте [JSON Assertion](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Assertion)

Если нужно проверить, чтобы пустое значение не приходило, нужно выбрать "Invert assertion" - тест будет падать, если будет получено это значение

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]